# Why does the proof of Hammersley-Clifford theorem need to validate the specific energy functions to be 0?

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, markov-process

I have seen two proofs of Hammersley-Clifford theorem:

The **first proof** comes from the book *Probabilistic Graphical Models Principles and Techniques (p129 – p132)*, this link is the screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgTz8.png

The **second proof** comes from this link:
*[http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/Courses/251.spring04/Handouts/Hammersley-Clifford.pdf](http://www.stat.yale.edu/%7Epollard/Courses/251.spring04/Handouts/Hammersley-Clifford.pdf)*

**For both proofs**:

**Firstly**, they rewrite the probability distribution function P(X) as the multiplication of energy functions.

**Secondly**, they **validate the values of some specific energy functions are constantly 0** if those funxtions containing variables that do not constitute clique in graph H.

I was confused by the second step, which seems complex and unnecessary.

Here is my proof to circumvent the second step: (Signs are consistent with the second proof)

Following the same first step, P(X) can be written as:

[image] ...(EQ.A)

T is the collection of all the combinations of variables x1, x2, x3…, A is one of these combinations.

In the book *Probabilistic Graphical Models Principles and Techniques (p39)*, according to Exercise 2.5, P(X) satisfies the following form when two sets of variables are conditionally independent:

[image]

Hence, in (EQ.A), if x1 and x2 do not constitute a clique in H, namely they are independent when conditioning on some other variables, then any A containing both x1 and x2 will lead to f(A)=CONSTANT to ensure P(X) can be written as the form of Exercise 2.5.

Hence, if some A does not result f(A)=CONSTANT, then it is the clique of H (except those A's that contain only one variable or nothing), so P(X) is the Gibbs distribution of H.